Ejecutar una tareda en php en segundo plano
tengo una tareaen php que cuando la ejecuto me dura aproximadamente 15 minutos, mientras esta se esta ejecutando todo el servidor se me queda colgado hasta que se termine y todo regresa a la normalidad, quisiera saber si ese tipo de consultas que son pesadas se pueden ejecutar en segundo plata.
Miguel tu estas en la uni? Pa ve si puedes preguntar por alla como ejecutar un proceso de php en segundo plano.
Vi que con  "popen()" se puede segun pero no entiendo muy bien
http://php.net/manual/es/function.popen.php
$command = "miarchivo.php";
pclose(popen('start /b php.exe '.$command, 'r'));
Coloco la ruta asi y me da error, debo colocar la ruta completa? A pesar que el archivo php donde llamo a popen esta en la misma carpeta.
Gracias de antemano

Miguel favor responder

Miguel, tu que estas en la uni, dile al OP que donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que ha hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que ha utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

Si el tipo de tarea que quieres realizar es pesado, lo seguirá siendo aunque la ejecutes en segundo plano y probablemente el servidor se seguirá bloqueando. Entonces convendría ver por qué esa tarea se hace pesada. ¿Es el código que está mal escrito? Por ejemplo podría estar entrando en bucles infinitos. ¿Es el diseño? ¿Es la infraestructura? Dependiendo del motivo, entonces podrás optimizar y/o replantear la forma de realizar esa tarea.

Ah oka asi se ejecute en segundo plano igual el servidor seguiria bloqueado hasta que termine de ejecutsr la tarea por completo? Pense que si la realizaba en segundo plano el servidor quedaria desbloqueado,  la tarea lo que hace es comunicarse con un api de whatsapp para enviar mensajes masivos quero como tiene q esperar 1 segundo por mensaje, por eso es que demora tanto en realizar todo si son unos 500 mensajes. Son como 500 segundos de demora

Una cosa es hacerla en segundo plano y otra es hacerlo por tuplas o colas, se me escapa el termino técnico correcto ahora. La cosa es dividir la macro tarea y hacerla que se ejecute por partes, algo como se hace con la paginación. Alguien que me ayude con el termino que se me ha ido

Ah ok entiendo, creo q esa podria ser una solucion si se pudiera ejecutar por cola o colocarle como que menos prioridad, la idea es que el servidor no quedara colgado por esa tarea ps que todo funcionara normal mientras ella va poco a poco ejecutandose... por que el problema no es la consulta si no la api que hace que para cada envia de whatsapp se espere un segundo y eso la frena y la deja retrasada, por que sin la api ps la consulta dura un parpadeo y listo.

En efecto, el API de WhatsApp espera 1 segundo por cada mensaje. Puedes dividir toda la tarea en bloques de X registros (de 500 en 500 por ejemplo) y así gestionar mejor los recursos. Quizás un cronjob podría ayudarte con ese tema.

@OCHOA el término es procesamiento por lotes.

Justo ese era @A.Cedano lo que paso es que en estos días tengo unos problemas y mi mente no anda al 100% en ningún área. Como siempre muy amable por la cooperación.

@OCHOA de nada. Y mucho ánimo. Muchas son las pruebas que esperan al justo, pero de todas lo libra el Señor (Salmo 34,19).

Gracias @A.Cedano a veces una palabra amiga en el momento preciso es todo lo que se necesita para no derrumbarse y seguir. Bendiciones mi estimado.

Para una ejecución en segundo plano y si no necesita ningún tipo de salida  lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código:
<?php
$command = "php miarchivo.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
exec($command);
?>

Explicación del código:
El PHP se ejecutará y la salida se redirigirá a /dev/null, lo que descartará cualquier salida en la ejecución. El "&" al final del comando indica que se debe ejecutar en segundo plano de forma asíncrona y evita que el servidor se bloquee.
